# Logging into Windows 11 account using a pasted password

Tags: login-screen, paste

I have a separate admin account on my home PC, to make it less likely I will go into the admin account I want to give it an extremely long alpha-numeric password that is near enough impossible for the likes of me to remember, the password is deciphered from my own convoluted process, because of its length typing in the result in the windows login screen would be next to impossible, but the pasting function seems to be disabled in the login screen, is there perhaps a command line option for login into another account?

Comment: Perhaps look at YubiKey to help you with this

Comment: The issue you are having isn't that pasting is disabled, but that there isn't a clipboard when the user isn't logged in, and each user has its own clipboard. if you login to a system using RDP or as a local VM, you can paste into the password box, because the users clipboard is accessible.

Comment: You may look at using alternative methods of login, for example your phone.

Comment: How do you log into your admin account from your phone?

Comment: @CodeVomit - [Windows supports it.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/sign-in-to-your-accounts-using-the-microsoft-authenticator-app-582bdc07-4566-4c97-a7aa-56058122714c#:~:text=Turn%20on%20phone%20sign-in%201%20Open%20the%20Microsoft,screen%20view%20of%20the%20account.%20...%20More%20items). Phones also can be used as NFC devices.